# Tango with Django: Creating a "Like" button

Tags: jquery, python, html, django

I am nearing completion of the Tango with Django tutorial, I'm near homestretch, in the process of making a 'like' button:

http://www.tangowithdjango.com/book17/chapters/ajax.html#add-a-like-button

What is supposed to happen is:

> when the button is clicked an AJAX request is made, given our url
>   mapping, this invokes the like_category view which updates the
>   category and returns the new number of likes. When the AJAX request
>   receives the response it updates parts of the page, i.e. the text and
>   the button. The #likes button is hidden.

My button is there, can be clicked, but does not hide after being clicked, nor does it actual increment the number of likes, and I'm not sure why, I successfully created buttons in the previous introductory chapter.

These are the relevant code snippets (but let me know if there is something that I missed which could be helpful:

```
views.py

@login_required
def like_category(request):

    cat_id = None
    if request.method == 'GET':
        cat_id = request.GET['category_id']

    likes = 0
    if cat_id:
        cat = Cat.objects.get(id=int(cat_id))
        if cat:
            likes = cat.likes + 1
            cat.likes =  likes
            cat.save()

    return HttpResponse(likes)
```

---

```
rango-ajax.js

$('#likes').click(function(){
    var catid;
    catid = $(this).attr("data-catid");
    $.get('/rango/like_category/', {category_id: catid}, function(data){
               $('#like_count').html(data);
               $('#likes').hide();
    });
});
```

---

```
category.html

<p>

<strong id="like_count">{{ category.likes }}</strong> people like this category

{% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <button id="likes" data-catid="{{ category.id }}" class="btn btn-primary" type="button">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></span>
    Like
    </button>
{% endif %}

</p>
```

---

```
models.py

from django.db import models
from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Category(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)
        views = models.IntegerField(default=0)
        likes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
        slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)

        def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
                self.slug = slugify(self.name)
                super(Category, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

        def __unicode__(self):
                return self.name
```

I do not know much about html or javascript/jquery, but I am wondering if the data-catid section of my category.html file is incorrect (even though this is how it is in the tutorial). I question it simply because notepad++ does not colour that attribute the way it does for 'id' or 'class'. Thoughts anyone?

Cheers,
Paul

EDIT:

This is what my console shows me when I click on the like button:

```
[19/Dec/2014 09:44:20] "GET /rango/like_category/?category_id=1 HTTP/1.1" 500 11493
```

Comment: Is the console error from your Python console or browser console? Also, check my 2nd edit.

Comment: You're a beast! Thanks so much for your help aus_lacy, I appreciate the time you put here, that second edit was the solution!

Comment: No problem, glad to help. I believe that it's a typo within the Tango with Django tutorial probably caused by updating various versions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `data-catid` is simply an attribute that is assigned to a given HTML tag similar to any other value attribute pair like  `id, class, title, etc.`.

Further explanation on the idea of setting attributes with jQuery can be found [here](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributes).

## EDIT

Django requires you to load static files on a template by template basis. In your `category.html` I'm assuming you have `{% extends base.html %}`, but directly under that you need `{% load static %}` and then you can reference your ajax script.

Example of `category.html` below:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block body_block %}
     <!-- Your template html here -->
     <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/rango-ajax.js' %}"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

## Edit 2

Try replacing

```
Cat.objects.get(id=int(cat_id))
```

with

```
Category.objects.get(id=int(cat_id))
```

Comment: Okay so that makes sense - any thoughts on why the button wouldnt be functioning as expected?

Comment: Added to original post - thanks for taking the time here @aus_lacy!

Comment: Don't see any errors with the model. Are you including your rango-ajax.js script in your template?

Comment: I was wondering if I was messing that up. I'm calling it in my base.html right before the </html>: <script src="{% static 'js/rango-ajax.js' %}"></script> Where static is the folder which holds my js folder and then the script.

Comment: Thanks for your answer - I didn't know that, but I was actually doing that anyways, but it's helpful to know that needs to be explicitely stated all the time. I added the console message that shows up when I click on the like button, if that's helpful.